# How to 'kitchen login' with user different from root

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

our main cookbook disables root login via ssh, but we want to be able to execute `kitchen login` to play with the test machine (yes, we can do it with ssh machine, but I want to know if it is possible to configure test-kitchen to use a custom user).

My question is 'Is it possible to configure test-kitchen to use the user ***steve*** instead of the root one when executing `kitchen login`?' I can't find anything about this in the net or the already asked questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is supported.  According to the [kitchen docs](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_kitchen.html), the only supported option is for setting the log level, not the user.  If this is something you need, I'd recommend filing a feature request.

Comment: Yeah, after looking at the source code, I'm sure that that's the case, for me adding a test environment that doesn't permit the root login works.